Tire schrader core replacement without deflation
Is there a way (tool) to replace the schrader valve core on a standard car tire valve that spares the need to deflate and reinflate the tire, just like there is a way to do it with an HVAC system charging port schraders (so that you don't have to recover the refrigerant)? I know there are simple tools like a screwdriver but they would involve deflating the tire. The HVAC tool I am talking about has a 2-chamber shutoff, which prevents leakout when the core is taken out. I am asking if there is the same tool but for car tires.

You could do it in a chamber that is pressurised to the same pressure as the tyre. If you want that much hassle... and the need to slowly depressurise to avoid the bends, if you're in the chamber.

While there may be one for tires, there really isn't a need for it. The difference between a tire and an A/C unit (of whatever flavor) is when you pull a tire core, it's only air coming out (even nitrogen filled ... plain air is ~78% nitrogen). With an A/C unit, you have refrigerant. If, when you pull the core, you have your replacement ready, you'll actually not lose that much air out of the tire. Again, it's not a big deal so there's really no need for one.

don't you need to wait for all the air to come out before you can insert the new core ?

@amphibient You shouldn't have to, if you're determined enough and show it you mean business, you should manage to get it in against the outflow (just hold the core firmly so that it doesn't fly off).

I know of no such tool for tires. If you are worried about the tire deflating and putting pressure on the sidewall then jack the car up some, you don't have to lift the tire all the way off the ground, just enough to ensure the weight of the car isn't going to rest on the rim.
